# Single command to insert date and time in datetime type, SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

In the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 database, how can I insert both date and time in a datetime typed column, in a single command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql query to insert datetime in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957635/sql-query-to-insert-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use the function NOW() in MSSQL you can use the GETDATE() function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx

Here's an example :

```
INSERT INTO `table`(`datetime`) VALUES(GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the [DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) value for the current session, and use INSERT command to add new record, e.g.:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 VALUES (1, '24-07-2012 12:45:10')

SET DATEFORMAT mdy;
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 VALUES (2, '07-24-2012 12:45:10')
```