# saving date time picker date in sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net-2010

how do I insert a datetimepicker date into sql server from vb.net.

Example of my code , just a piece, where birthdate is the datetimepicker control

this is my code for

```
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthdate", birthdate.Value)
```

and here is the insert into command:

```
("Insert into [BD_maest].[dbo].[cust] ([Birthdate]) values ('" + birthdate.value + "')", conec)
```

I'm getting this error when trying to save data:
**conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date string you are passing to sql is not in a format sql will recognise.
You could cast value to a DateTime object and use the date time in your sql command. Here is an example (using a parameter for the birthdate - which you probably want to do)

```
Dim Birthdate As New System.DateTime(YYYY, MM, DD)
Dim sql as String ="Insert into [BD_maest].[dbo].[cust] ([Birthdate]) values ('@birthdate')", conec).
cmd.Connection = conec
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText= sql
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('birthdate',Birthdate)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Or make sure your birthDate value is in the form YYYYMMDD which will be understood by sql server:

```
("Insert into [BD_maest].[dbo].[cust] ([Birthdate]) values ('" + YYYYMMDD + "')", conec).
```

see this question for more options:
[Sql query to insert datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957635/sql-query-to-insert-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thank you @iceburg, it has been much help. I did this and it worked: birthdate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd")