# How to INSERT date into SQL database date column using dateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetimepicker

I have a birthdate column of type `Date` in sql database

And in my application I use a `dateTimePicker` to get the birth date

But when i am trying to insert the `date` taken from the `dateTimePicker`:

I get an error :

> Incorrect syntax near '12'

And when I try to debug the code I find that the value taken from the `dateTimePicker` is

Date = `{3/21/2015 12:00:00 AM}`

The CODE:

```
//cmd is sql command
cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO person (birthdate) VALUES("+dateTimePicker.Value.Date+")";
//con is sql connection
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957635/sql-query-to-insert-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Also check datatype of birthdate in table

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you **really** should do is use **parameters** to avoid SQL injection attacks - and it also frees you from string formatting dates - also a good thing!

```
//cmd is sql command
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Person(birthdate) VALUES(@Birthdate);";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Birthdate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker.Value.Date;

//con is sql connection
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Also, it's a recommend best practice to put your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` into `using(....) { .... }` blocks to ensure proper disposal:

```
string connectionString = ".......";
string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Person(birthdate) VALUES(@Birthdate);";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@Birthdate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker.Value.Date;

     con.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before the best practice is to use parameters, but if you really need to use a TSQL statement from source you should use date in the format: yyyymmdd

```
cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO person (birthdate) VALUES('"+dateTimePicker.Value.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+"')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including quotes:

```
cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO person (birthdate) VALUES('"+dateTimePicker.Value.Date+"')";
```

I'd recommend using parameters too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as string format:

```
cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO person(birthdate)VALUES('"+dateTimePicker.Value.Date+"')";
```

Comment: You forgot a space before `VALUES`

Answer (score 0):

`dateTimePicker` stores values as `1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM` so you should use `DATETIME` if you're trying to store it since DATETIME's format is: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS`.

You can print the `dateTimePicker` value using

```
MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker.Value.ToString());
```

to see for yourself.

Comment: Add more info on this.