# DataTimePicker and Checkbox insert to database - Error SQL Syntax

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datetime, checkbox

I'm programming in C#.NET and in MySQL. My database is named "projekt1". I've created new form InsertStatus.cs which contains: 3 textboxes, 1 numericUpDown, 2 dataTimePickers and 2 checkboxes.

I have connection with local database. I wrote SQL with INSERT INTO  Correctly but it couldn't write that date and time do this database. And shows that is "an error SQL syntax". I've tried with  *.Value.ToString()*  and  *.Value*  and it didn't work. I would like to change customFormat in dataTimePickers to DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM (I mean in settings on the right site not in code) but i'm not sure if it could work. In below there is this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace KontrolaBazaDanych

{
    public partial class InsertStatus : Form
    {
        public InsertStatus()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=");
        string InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO project1.status_order(ID_ORDER, ID_WORKER, ID_MODULE, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, DATE_OF_START, DATE_OF_END, ORDER_DONE, ORDER_STARTED) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + numericUpDown1.Value + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + "','" + checkBox1.ToString() + "','" + checkBox2.ToString() + "')'";
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(InsertQuery, connection);

            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("DATA IS ADDED.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR.");
            }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

// SQL COLUMNS IN status_order table:

```
ID_ORDER INT,
ID_WORKER INT,
ID_MODULE INT, 
AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS INT, 
DATE_OF_START DATETIME, 
DATE_OF_END DATETIME, 
ORDER_DONE BOOLEAN, 
ORDER_STARTED BOOLEAN;
```

I have no idea what i should do. Can someone please explain how can i change. Thank you for any help or advice.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29183034/5346438

Comment: is it not supposed to be datepicker.SelectedDate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this in the Code

`dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm")`

Comment: hmm... what about `checkbox1`? Should be `checkbox1.Value.Tostring()` too?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString()
```

You convert your date to string even though your database has datetime columns

```
DATE_OF_START DATETIME, 
DATE_OF_END DATETIME,
```

Comment: hmm... what about `checkbox1`? Should be `checkbox1.Value.Tostring()` too?

Comment: I would try to write bool to the data base as first resort and cast it to string later if it's not working. did it fix your problem btw?