# date time is not working in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table called `Tbl_Sud_Details` it has three columns:

```
Name is varchar(),
Course is varchar(),
DateofAdmission is Datetime(),
```

When I am inserting a date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` it gives the error:

> Error:The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into  Tbl_Sud_Details(Name,Course,DateofAdmission)Values('" + ddlname.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + txtcourse.Text + "','" +Convert.ToDateTime(txtAdddate.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "')", con);
con.Open();
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
if (i > 0)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert(\"data is  save Successfully \"); </script>");
    return;

}
```

Answer (score 6):

`"dd/MM/yyyy"` is not supported by SQL. try `"yyyy-MM-dd"` instead. To avoid injection attacks i would use parameters to submit data.

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    string stm = "Insert into  Tbl_Sud_Details(Name,Course,DateofAdmission)Values(@Name,@Course,@DateofAdmission)";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stm))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlname.SelectedItem.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Course", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtcourse.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateofAdmission", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtAdddate.Text);

        con.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: i want insert with c# code with textbox i was already mention above

Comment: *"dd/MM/yyyy" is not supported by SQL* - Yes it is, but could return an error if regional settings are for a DATEFORMAT of `MDY` rather than `DMY`. +1 nonetheless because this becomes irrelevant with parameterised queries.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which database backend you use, you may have to encode dates differently.

For an example in SQL server, see this question: 
[Sql query to insert datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957635/sql-query-to-insert-datetime-in-sql-server/12957690)

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 R2 all the above is not working provided by you

Answer (score 0):

SQL Understand this format **"yyyy-MM-dd"**. So your custom datetime format must follow default datetime. When you send default datetime, it then understand by sql. also in ui for client view, you can manage this by formatting it as your need but when sending to database must follow the default format

Answer (score 0):

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Tbl_Sud_Details(Name,Course,DateofAdmission)Values('" + ddlname.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + txtcourse.Text + "',CONVERT(datetime,'" + txtAdddate.Text + "',103))", con);