# Adding a date of birth into table

Tags: sql

How can I add a date of birth into a table? I'm not sure how to properly format using the TO_CHAR function. Currently have

```
INSERT INTO Participant (PartDOB,)
VALUES (TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY')'18-09-1964')
```

But it just returns with "missing comma". What's the correct way to format it?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: As Gordon showed in his answer, the best way is not to format at all! If you want to add a date, use a date datatype, it's what it's there for!

Comment: Remove that ending comma in the insert column list.

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957635/sql-query-to-insert-datetime-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most databases, just use ISO standard date formats:

```
INSERT INTO Participant (PartDOB, . . .)
    VALUES ('1964-09-18', . . .)
```

In Oracle (suggested by `TO_CHAR()` and `sysdate`), you need to precede this with `DATE` to indicate a date constant:

```
INSERT INTO Participant (PartDOB, . . .)
    VALUES (DATE '1964-09-18', . . .)
```

You would use `sysdate` just to get the current date/time.

Comment: And also ANSI SQL requires the `DATE` keyword, just like Oracle.