# Sql Server how to insert date into column with date datatype

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-insert

I am trying to insert birthday date into column date within `Sql Server 2008 r2`
db I tried to pass it as below but none of them are worked out

[image]

```
INSERT INTO t1 (birthday) VALUES (cast(08/12/2010 as date))
```

> Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Explicit conversion from data type
>   int to date is not allowed.

```
INSERT INTO t1 (birthday) VALUES (20100812)
```

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

```
INSERT INTO t1 (birthday) VALUES (20100812)

INSERT INTO t1 (birthday) VALUES ('20100812')
```

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

```
INSERT INTO t1 (birthday) VALUES ('2010-08-12')
```

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: If you're passing this data from e.g. [tag:c#], please pass it *as* a `date` parameter. ADO.Net knows how to translate a .NET `DateTime` into an SQL `date` (or `datetime2`, etc) and you can avoid mucking about with strings/formatting entirely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql query to insert datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957635/sql-query-to-insert-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour OF COURSE  I searched and tried a lot before posting and tried this answer too but it wont work !

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ummm yes I am going to pass it from c# later on but for now I am testing the procedure that will be called from c# ... dose that mean that `sql server` will work in different way ?!!

Comment: So, stop thinking about SQL from a *strings* perspective. Using parameters has lots of advantages, one of which (here) is that you don't have to pass your data *unnaturally* as a string and then force SQL Server to parse it *back* into the correct type (because it's the conversion to and from strings that *introduces* formatting and parsing issues, so if you can avoid those conversions, you should try to do so)

Comment: @sam the errors say you tried to store dates into a *int* column, not a `date`. `INSERT INTO t1 (birthday) VALUES ('20100812')` works, in fact it's the only format that *isn't* affected by locale. The other will also work if they match the column's collation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank for helpful info I tried but it gives `Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type varchar to numeric.` and also I had update my post with screenshot to prove that column is date datatype in the database

Comment: @sam are you targeting the wrong table perhaps? The screenshot doesn't say anything, except perhaps that you are looking at the wrong table

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I will give it a try

Comment: @sam post the *actual* table definition command, *actual* INSERT queries. A simple `CREATE #t1 (birthday date); INSERT INTO #t1 (birthday) VALUES ('20100812')` will be enough to reproduce the problem. I'll bet it won't.

Comment: Are there any triggers involved?

Answer (score 2):

From your edit and error messages generated, it looks like `birthday` column isn't of `DATE` datatype

Correct that and this will work

```
INSERT INTO t1 (birthday) VALUES (cast(08/12/2010 as date))
```

or

```
INSERT INTO t1 (birthday) VALUES ('20101210')
```

Full repo - Working

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (Birthday DATE)

INSERT INTO dbo.T1 ( Birthday)
VALUES ('20181010') 

INSERT INTO dbo.T1 ( Birthday)
VALUES (CAST('20181010' AS DATE) )

SELECT * FROM dbo.T1

Birthday
2018-10-10
2018-10-10
```

Error Repo (1) - Enter a Date value into an INT column

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (Birthday INT)

INSERT INTO dbo.T1 ( Birthday)
VALUES (CAST('20181010' AS DATE) )
```

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 7 Operand type clash: date is
>   incompatible with int

Error Repo (2) - Enter a Date value into an NUMERIC column

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (Birthday NUMERIC)

INSERT INTO dbo.T1 ( Birthday)
VALUES (CAST('20181010' AS DATE) )
```

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 7 Operand type clash: date is
>   incompatible with numeric

Error Repo (3) - Enter a INT value into a DATE column

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (Birthday DATE)

INSERT INTO dbo.T1 ( Birthday)
VALUES (20181010)
```

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 6 Operand type clash: int is
>   incompatible with date

Comment: sorry mistyping error it just an example the exception will be different

Comment: you can see that I tried them again  exception will be different in case the column is not in correct datatype

Comment: What is the datatype of the column ? Include it in your question

Comment: column datatype is date

Comment: @sam `date` works in all SQL Server versions since 2005.  `20100812` works. If it didn't, people would have noticed 13 years ago. Post the *actual* table definition and *actual* queries. Post something that can be used to reproduce what you claim. The errors say you tried to store data into a `int`column

Comment: @sam, the error messages you've posted show that the datatype of the Birthday column is incorrect

Comment: @Mazhar and the screenshot of the column is date

Comment: @Mazhar is the collection of the database has effect on that ?

Comment: As mentioned in earlier comments, if you're certain the datatype is correct then your code is trying to insert into a different table on perhaps a different db

Answer (score 1):

Almost there. Try

`INSERT INTO t1 (birthday) VALUES ('2010-08-12')`

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: Can you tell me the datatype of birthday column

Comment: If that's the error message, then the column datatype isn't date. Please correct your question.

Comment: @JorgeAguiar the unseparated format is the only one that isn't affected by the locale.The error though suggest the OP used an int column or targeted the wrong table

Answer (score 1):

Even though it was asked 1 year back but still for others reference if you use below code it should work:
INSERT INTO t1 (birthday) VALUES (convert(date,'08/12/2010'))

Also dates should not be inserted in ddmmyyyy format which is very common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In the insert, you mentioned two columns i.e. ID and NUM.

Bet you mentioned only 1 values: Hence

```
INSERT INTO t1 (ID,NUM) VALUES (1, '20100812')
```

- Answer to Modified question:

The data type of column ***NUM*** is numeric and you are trying to insert an `varchar`.

Hence correct your datatype for column NUM or insert into correct column.

Comment: sorry mistyping error it just an example the exception will be different

Comment: You made a mistake in typing and gave us a -1. WOW!

Comment: @ exception will be different in case the column is not in correct datatype !!