# Insert Convert TimeStamp to Numeric

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert type `date/datetime` to `numeric` type in SQL server. I have tried this code:

```
insert INTO aa (data) values (Convert(Numeric, date(),102));
```

Maybe you have solution?

Comment: What numeric representation of the date do you want here?

Comment: Please see this solution maybe helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957635/sql-query-to-insert-datetime-in-sql-server/12957690

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I did earlier  We can only convert `nvarchar` to int, not in Numeric.

```
insert INTO aa (data) values (Convert(int, date(),102));
```

Comment: @firmanbr using the wrong type *creates* problems. Why store the date as a number in the first place? Why not use a `date` field?