# What's the default format for date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am using a stored procedure for inserting data into a table. But when I execute it and insert a date (I inserted date as: `02.08.1999`), I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '.1999'.

Why is this happening? Am I inserting date in a wrong format?
I am using date datatype not datetime
Values I pass to my stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @return_value INT

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[insStd]
        @StdID = 6,
        @SName = N'Sarath',
        @FName = N'dsg',
        @Dob = 12.09.1999,
        @Gender = N'M',
        @SAddress = N'fsdf',
        @SState = N'fdsf',
        @Spincode = N'324',
        @SMobile = N'66757657',
        @SEmail = N'fdsf',
        @SPphone = N'45456',
        @SDegree = N'bsc',
        @YoC = 2019,
        @SPercentage = 75,
        @SCollege = N'sn',
        @username = N'sarath',
        @pswd = N'sarath'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: Date doesn't have a format in SQL Server, it's a binary data.

Comment: Try 'YYYY-MM-DD' format

Comment: none, there is no date format. The format you see is depending on the software you are using, most use the regional options for that

Comment: [this](http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes) should have some answers for you

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957635/sql-query-to-insert-datetime-in-sql-server?

Comment: For literal date values, use an ISO 8601 date format.

Comment: @RedDevil dates are binary values, they have no format. *String literals* can be parsed into dates but even then, only the unseparated format is unambiguous. `YYYY-MM-DD` is affected by the `DATEFORMAT` setting

Comment: @marc_s "fun" fact - looks like only `datetime` gets confused by `DATEFORMAT`. Newer types treat `YYYY-MM-DD` properly. `set dateformat dmy;
declare @date datetime2='2017-12-31'` works while `datetime` throws a conversion error

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yes, that is correct - but unfortunately, the `DATETIME` type is still very widely used, therefore to be on the safe side,I'd stick with `YYYYMMDD`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql query to insert datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957635/sql-query-to-insert-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And I'd add that even as datetime usage goes down, it is better to use a format that will work everywhere, than one that has to assume everyone is using a very specific set of types.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to pass in a `DATE` as a string literal - you have to format it **as a string literal**, which means putting it in **single quotes**

```
DECLARE @return_value INT

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[insStd]
        @StdID = 6,
        @SName = N'Sarath',
        @FName = N'dsg',
        @Dob = '12.09.1999',  -- SINGLE QUOTES!!!
        @Gender = N'M',
        @SAddress = N'fsdf',
        @SState = N'fdsf',
        @Spincode = N'324',
        @SMobile = N'66757657',
        @SEmail = N'fdsf',
        @SPphone = N'45456',
        @SDegree = N'bsc',
        @YoC = 2019,
        @SPercentage = 75,
        @SCollege = N'sn',
        @username = N'sarath',
        @pswd = N'sarath'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

And to avoid any issues with date formatting depending on language/regional settings, it's recommended to use the (modified) **ISO-8601** dateformat: `YYYYMMDD`:

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[insStd]
        @StdID = 6,
        @SName = N'Sarath',
        @FName = N'dsg',
        @Dob = '19990912',  -- ISO-8601 and SINGLE QUOTES
        @Gender = N'M',
        @SAddress = N'fsdf',
        @SState = N'fdsf',
        @Spincode = N'324',
        @SMobile = N'66757657',
        @SEmail = N'fdsf',
        @SPphone = N'45456',
        @SDegree = N'bsc',
        @YoC = 2019,
        @SPercentage = 75,
        @SCollege = N'sn',
        @username = N'sarath',
        @pswd = N'sarath'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```