# how to convert timestamp in python to overcome 1..12 issue

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to execute a sql query with Python code and am getting error month muct be in 1..12

I have surfed the net but couldn't find anything related to this issue.

```
sql = '''
        INSERT INTO {Database}.{Schema}.Instance (
              Id
            , DateTime
            , Period
            , StatusId
        ) VALUES (
            ?,
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            ?,
            ?
        );
    '''
self['_repository'].execute_query(sql, str(self.id), period, Instance.INITIALISED)
```

When I am executing the code it gives me an error "month must be in 1..12"

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: What does the definition of `Instance` look like?

Comment: looks like a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12957690/9216722 . You have to convert CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to format which datetime type supports.

Comment: Database is SQL DB and Instance is the table name

Comment: What is SQL DB? Microsoft SQL engine?

Comment: whats the format of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP you are inserting to table?

Comment: It's Azure SQL DB. I need to insert Y-M-D H:M:S:f. How to incorporate this change in the code to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
sql = '''
        INSERT INTO {Database}.{Schema}.Instance (
              Id
            , DateTime
            , Period
            , StatusId
        ) VALUES (
            ?,
            CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DateTime)
            ?,
            ?
        );
    '''
self['_repository'].execute_query(sql, str(self.id), period, Instance.INITIALISED)
```

Can you try this?

Comment: Same error, 2019-10-31 06:28:33,349 ERROR scheduler.main month must be in 1..12
2019-10-31 06:28:33,349 ERROR month must be in 1..12

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to help you out.

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
sql = '''
    INSERT INTO {Database}.{Schema}.Instance (
          Id
        , DateTime
        , Period
        , StatusId
    ) VALUES (
        ?,
        '''
        +
        timestamp
        +
        '''
        ?,
        ?
    );
'''
self['_repository'].execute_query(sql, str(self.id), period, Instance.INITIALISED)
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, but still getting error ERROR Invalid column name 'timestamp'.

Comment: Need help on this please

Comment: use sting concatenation  like '''string'''+timestamp+'''string''' in your query..

Comment: can you give me the query please

Comment: what is the field of date? Is it timestamp or DATE?

Comment: Apologize for late reply. It is datetime2 datatype.

Comment: Hi Adam, INSERT is working fine now. But when I am using SELECT statement, the error pops up when I am trying to get the datetime field. Datetime coulmn is in datetime2 datatype.

Comment: I tried CAST(<COulmnname>,datetime2) , CAST(<columnname>,datetime2(7) both didn't work