# InvalidQueryParameterValue error related BlobContainerClient FindBlobsByTags

Tags: c#, sql, azure

I want to filter my blob storage files by tags. Following two lines works fine.

```
var query = "Client = '"+req.Client+"' AND Type = '"+req.Type+"'";

var foundItems = sourceClient.FindBlobsByTags(query).ToList();
```

But if I add another date(string since SetBlobTags only support string) parameter, I get `InvalidQueryParameterValue`

```
var query = "Client = '"+req.Client+"' AND Type = '"+req.Type+"' AND Timestamp >= '"+req.Date.ToString()+"'";
    
    var foundItems = sourceClient.FindBlobsByTags(query).ToList();
```

I got the following error.

```
Status: 400 (Error parsing query at or near character position 45: unexpected '1')
ErrorCode: InvalidQueryParameterValue

Additional Information:
QueryParameterName: where
QueryParameterValue: Client = 'ABC' AND Type = 'Application' AND Timestamp >= '1/17/2023 1:21:56 PM'
Reason: This query parameter value is invalid.
```

What's wrong with my query?

According to website, it supports >=

"The storage service supports a subset of the ANSI SQL WHERE clause grammar for the value of the where=expression query parameter. The following operators are supported: =, >, >=, <, <=, AND. and @container. Example expression: "tagKey"='tagValue'."

Comment: even with parameters, which would be the **best** way to pass values, you need **always** a compatible date type, or use a convertion to get the correct datetype

Comment: @nbk I converted the date to string, so it should work? no?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query to insert datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957635/sql-query-to-insert-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I add the backslash, it works fine.

```
"\"Timestamp\" >= '"+req.Date.ToString()"'"
```